# Django global user management

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I think I understand how the User model in each app is used and can be extended, but is it possible to set User authentication and management at a project level, so that settings here is propagated to all apps, without repeating User model specifics in each app?
Look at the following example:

- Project xyz

  - ----App1
  - ----App2

If I have users divided in 3 groups, where

- group1, has access to App1 but not App2
- group2, has access to App2 but not App1
- group3, has access to both apps.

From what I understand I have to set up my user model in each of the apps, and if I make changes or extend the User model in one of the apps, I have to repeat this process in all the other apps. But this has to be wrong and I have to have misunderstood something? Is there any inheritance here that I have overlooked?

Comment: Do you have a specific programming question?

Comment: No, actually, my question might be phrased wrong, but I was asking for some guidance as to if my understanding is correct or maybe an explanation as to how this concept works in django.

Comment: You don't have to set up a User model in each app. In fact, that sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: But without seeing your code, it's impossible to know exactly what you mean, and which concepts you might have misunderstood.

Comment: And I think you're giving too much importance to apps. They're just a collection of models and views, nothing else.